# Shopify: Variables Available on Thank You Page?

Tags: rest, shopify

I've got a small bit of code on my Shopify thank you page for a home grown fulfillment system. In oversimplified terms, it outputs a URL with template code that uses the `{{id}}` field.

```
<p>
    Your order information is {{id}}!  This is not the actual code, 
    this is just an oversimplified version for this question
</p>
```

Up until a few weeks ago, the `{{id}}` template variable would output the ID of the order object.  I use this ID and the Shopify `REST` api to fetch order information. Now, for reasons that remain unclear to me, this outputs a different number that appears to be the `checkout-id` field.

Is this intended behavior?  Is there anyway to get the old, real order object ID back?  I can think of numerous ways to work around this, but I'd rather not mess with a system that's worked in a stable way for the past 5 years.

Comment: What do you mean you use the REST API to fetch order information? Shopify provides you with order information in Liquid on the Thank You page.

Comment: @DavidLazar That's not very clear in my post -- my apologies. On the actual page I use the ID (and other information) to link the user off to a page where they can download their order.  That line's basically there to counter any "why do you need to do this" response.

Comment: @AlanStorm did you try order.id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation on this is spotty at best, but it seems like the old global liquid variables I've been using have changed their behavior. Acording to [Shopify's documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/checkout-page/thankyou-page), on that Thank You page

> You have access to the checkout and shop liquid objects

There's documentation on both the [checkout](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/checkout) and [shop](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/shop) objects, and I was able to get the old behavior I was after by replacing `{{id}}` with `{{checkout.order_id}}`.

It also appears there's a [liquid order object](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/order) available as well, but given it's not documented as being available on the checkout page, I'm not sure I'd trust it to keep working.

Comment: It has been suggested in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76044189/5211833), which should've been a comment, that the documentation URLs have changed.